# Symfony2 doctrine reverse engineering issue

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

After I executed the commands explained in the Symfony2 Book:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

It created correctly the XML files, generated correctly the entities.

But when I run:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

It says:

> [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
>
> [Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.

Ok so I following the tutorials I run:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

And here I can see that there are a lot of ALTER TABLE commands. Like this:

```
ALTER TABLE ea_restaurant_tag DROP FOREIGN KEY ea_restaurant_tag_ibfk_1;

ALTER TABLE ea_restaurant_tag DROP FOREIGN KEY ea_restaurant_tag_ibfk_2;

ALTER TABLE ea_restaurant_tag CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, CHANGE restaurant_id restaurant_id INT DEFAULT NULL, CHANGE login_id login_id INT DEFAULT NULL;

ALTER TABLE ea_restaurant_tag ADD CONSTRAINT FK_10C17C7E5CB2E05D FOREIGN KEY (login_id) REFERENCES ea_login (id);

ALTER TABLE ea_restaurant_tag ADD CONSTRAINT FK_10C17C7EB1E7706E FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_id) REFERENCES ea_restaurant (id);
```

**UPDATED**

This is the SQL "create" command for the restaurant_tag table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ea_restaurant_tag` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`restaurant_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`login_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `login_id` (`login_id`),
KEY `restaurant_id` (`restaurant_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `ea_restaurant_tag`
ADD CONSTRAINT `ea_restaurant_tag_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`restaurant_id`)      REFERENCES `ea_restaurant` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `ea_restaurant_tag_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`login_id`) REFERENCES  `ea_login` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

XML generated by Doctribne

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-  mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping  http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
<entity name="AppBundle\Entity\EaRestaurantTag" table="ea_restaurant_tag">
<indexes>
  <index name="login_id" columns="login_id"/>
  <index name="restaurant_id" columns="restaurant_id"/>
</indexes>
<id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
  <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
</id>
<field name="date" type="datetime" column="date" nullable="false">
  <options>
    <option name="default">CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</option>
  </options>
</field>
<many-to-one field="login" target-entity="EaLogin" fetch="LAZY">
  <join-columns>
    <join-column name="login_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
  </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
<many-to-one field="restaurant" target-entity="EaRestaurant" fetch="LAZY">
  <join-columns>
    <join-column name="restaurant_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
  </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
```

It's very strange it tries to delete the current keys and recreate others.
Why this happens ?

The database is MySQL and all tables are InnoDB.

Comment: Please paste your "create table " command from MySQL and the XML generated. Thanks

Comment: Added in the question. Thank you.

Comment: Try adding the `onDelete="CASCADE"` option to the join column Doctrine is trying to recreate. This might be the reason Doctrine does not recognize your current foreign key.

Comment: nothing changes. But the issue above happen in every table of database. It's incredible. In every foreign key it says to delete it and created again. It's not normal.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine import tool doesn't support unsigned primary keys. You probably has to define it manually by setting `columnDefinition="INTEGER UNSIGNED"` in JoinColumn or extending EntityGenerator class.